# Has anyone used lucene.net with Linq-to-Entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities, lucene, lucene.net

If anyone has done this, please let me know. I don't know anything about lucene.net. I have never used it, but I heard about it. I was wondering how something like that would integrate with the Linq entity framework?

Comment: so.. any update on this? I'm about to dive in head first, so if you have any remarks, please make them public :)

Comment: Sorry, I never ended up using it for the project I was working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Linq to Lucene](http://www.codeplex.com/linqtolucene) project.