# Question on Entity Framework and full-text search

Tags: entity-framework, full-text-search, lucene

Both Entity Framework and NHibernate are O-R mapping framework. Hibernate can use Lucene as full-text solution.

Is there any solution combine Entity framework and Lucene for searching? Where to find out the example/resource for this solution?

Answer (score 2):

[This thread discussing LINQ-to-Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153290/has-anyone-used-lucene-net-with-linq-to-entities) may be helpful.